# How to show progress in the parallel threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, parallel-processing

I have a code like this:

```
procedure TSeries.Read;
var
 ReadProc: TParallelFunction2;
 Counter:  integer;
begin
 try
  ProgressForm.Show;
  Counter  := 0;
  ReadProc :=
   procedure (i1, i2, tdi: integer)
   var
    i: integer;
   begin
    for i := i1 to i2 do
     if not FDASlice[i].PctPresent then
     begin
      TInterlocked.Increment(Counter);
      ReadSlice(i, True);
     end;
   end;

  Parallel.ForI(0, High, ReadProc, pfDivide);
 finally
  ProgressForm.HideForm;
 end;
end;
```

It uses the STParallel library to process the ReadProc procedure in the multi-threading mode. All works fine, but I need to show the progress to the user.
I try to add the 'Application.ProcessMessage' + 'ProgressForm.SpTBXProgressBar1.Position := Counter' into the ReadProc, or the 'TThread.Synchronize' with no success. Application hangs, progress doesn't shows.

How I can do show the progress? Is it possible in that code at all, or it's needed to move all not-main threads to other place? Thank you.

Comment: `TThread.Queue(nil, procedure begin Inc(Counter); ProgressBar.Position := Counter; end);` should work. You eliminate the interlocked operation as well.

Comment: @LURD It works, but at a cost. The performance is worse than atomic increment + UI timer driven update.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes the overhead of the queue call is definitely larger than the atomic increment. If this matters is difficult to say though.

Comment: I've try this code:

       TInterlocked.Increment(Counter);
      if Counter mod 10 = 0 then
       TThread.Queue(nil, procedure begin ProgressForm.SetPos(Counter); Application.ProcessMessages; end);
      ReadFirstSlice(i, True);
and it works nearly perfect.

Comment: Do not pump up the message queue (`Application.ProcessMessages`). Instead you could `Repaint` controls that need a refresh. But even that is not a good way. Consider what happens if the progress will be very fast. The user won't even notice any progress movement and you'll be unecessarily wasting system resources. The proposed timer solution is a way to go.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for all. I already changed ProcessMessages to the Repaint. And look for re-order the code in the near future.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest, and best, way to deal with this is to have the main thread update the progress on a timer.

You need to give the timer event access to the progress counter. That means converting the `Counter` variable from a local variable, to be a variable of a class that the UI can access. You don't need to synchronize access to the counter because the UI is not modifying it, and you already use an atomic increment function to modify the counter.

So, the steps you need are:

1. Move the `Counter` variable to be a member of a class, one that the UI can access.
2. Add a timer to the UI with an appropriate update frequency. An timer interval of 100ms will be more than adequate.
3. In the timer event set the progress bar's position to the instantaneous value of the counter.

So why is this approach better than yours? Well, progress UI updates should not be driven by the worker threads. Doing so runs the risk of overwhelming the UI with refreshes. This can put a serious block on perfmance and scalability.

Instead have the workers update progress state, but let the UI remain in charge of driving the updates. The UI knows that there's no point refreshing too frequently, and only it is in a position to determine refresh rate.